# How to convert an existing related field into a computed one in Odoo 13?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I have this existing field:

```
picking_code = fields.Selection(
    related='picking_id.picking_type_id.code',
    readonly=True,
)
```

And I want to inherit it, remove the `related` parameter and add a `compute` one to set its value depending on some conditions.

My attempt:

```
@api.depends('picking_id', 'picking_id.picking_type_id',
             'picking_id.picking_type_id.code',
             'move_id', 'move_id.picking_type_id',
             'move_id.picking_type_id.code')
def _compute_picking_code(self):
    _logger.critical('NEVER EXECUTES THIS' * 80)
    for line in self:
        if line.picking_id:
            line.picking_code = line.picking_id.picking_type_id.code
        else:
            line.picking_code = line.move_id.picking_type_id.code

picking_code = fields.Selection(
    related=False,
    compute='_compute_picking_code',
)
```

The problem is that the compute method is never executed and I get the following error, which makes sense since if the compute method is not executed, no selection value is set to the field:

> AssertionError: Field stock.move.line.picking_code without selection - - -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, if anyone is interested on the subject, it is a `Selection` field, so if remove the `related` parameter I have to specify again the list of tuples for the `selection` parameter.

```
picking_code = fields.Selection(
    selection=[
        ('incoming', 'Receipt'),
        ('outgoing', 'Delivery'),
        ('internal', 'Internal Transfer'),
    ],
    compute='_compute_picking_code',
    related=False,
    readonly=True,
)
```

Comment: If you have normal field and try to convert into compute  you must have to set store=True otherwise field will not store in database. Also related =False not needed in syntax.

Comment: In this case I did not want to store the field in database since the original one was not stored. I had to specify `related=False` to remove the previous related value the original field had.